# Method Marshaller errors in protoc generated Grpc Services on Android

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, grpc-java, protobuf-java

I have a server running the `grpc` endpoints which I'd like to connect to using an android client. I am trying to generate the required `..Grpc.java` so that I could use the `.newStub()` methods for creating a `grpc` request.

I have a proto file which contains the service as follows:

```
service StorageNode {
  rpc SayHello (StrWrapper) returns (StrWrapper) {}
}

message StrWrapper {
  string message = 1;
}
```

My android app `build.gradle` contains the `protobuf` task and dependencies listed as follows:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.9.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                javalite { }
                grpc {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     ...
     compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.0'
     compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.11.0'
     compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.11.0'
     compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.11.0'
}
```

The generated `ProtoFileGrpc.java` file contains errors once it builds as follows:

```
Error:(51, 64) error: method marshaller in class ProtoUtils cannot be applied to given types;
required: T
found: StrWrapper
reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
inferred: StrWrapper
upper bound(s): Message
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Message declared in method <T>marshaller(T)

Error:(927, 40) error: cannot find symbol method getDescriptor()

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be because `javax.annotation-api` was not included among the dependencies. This is necessary for `@javax.annotation.Generated` which the generated `...Grpc.java` seem to be using.

Including the following seems to have fixed the problem.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2"
}
```